# Convert color channels from BGR to RGB

Tags: java, opencv

I am working on a video capture project with OpenCV. I have been able to get the video capture to work but I want to change the camera filter to the "regular" spectrum so that the banana isn't blue and is yellow lol. This would be the RGB spectrum. I do the conversions in my program in the for loop but my camera view is still BRG. Here is an image.[image]

How can I get the image view to show "true" colors? Here is my code.

**Mat to Image Class**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;

public class Mat2Image {
    Mat mat = new Mat();
    private int argb = 0;
    Color c = new Color(argb, true);
    BufferedImage img;
    byte [] dat;

    Mat2Image(){
    }

    public Mat2Image(Mat mat) {
        getSpace(mat);
    }

    public void getSpace(Mat mat) {
        this.mat = mat;
        int w = mat.cols(), h = mat.rows();
        if (dat == null || dat.length != w * h * 3)
            dat = new byte[w * h * 3];
        if (img == null || img.getWidth() != w || img.getHeight() != h || img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
            img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);

        int[] holder = new int[w * h];
        holder =  img.getData().getPixels(0, 0, w, h, (int[]) null);
        for (int i = 0; i < dat.length; i++) {

            int blueChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 4;
            int greenChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF00) >> 2;
            int redChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF);
            int rgb = (blueChannel) & (greenChannel << 2) & (redChannel << 4);

            dat[i] = (byte) rgb;
        }
    }   

    BufferedImage getImage(Mat mat) {
        getSpace(mat);
        mat.get(0, 0, dat);
        img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat.cols(), mat.rows(), dat);
        return img;
    }
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
}
```

**Video Capture Class**

```
    public class VideoCap {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    }
    int currFrame = 0;
    VideoCapture cap;
    Mat2Image mat2Img = new Mat2Image();

    VideoCap() {
        cap = new VideoCapture();
        cap.open(0);
    }

    BufferedImage getOneFrame() {
        currFrame++;
        //currFrame is just to stop the camera of after the running for a bit.
        if (currFrame == 20) {
            cap.read(mat2Img.mat);
            System.exit(0);
        }
        cap.read(mat2Img.mat);

        return mat2Img.getImage(mat2Img.mat);
    }
}
```

**My JFrame Class**

```
    public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    MyFrame frame = new MyFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public MyFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100,100,650,490);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5,5,5,5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        new MyThread().start();
    }

    VideoCap videoCap = new VideoCap();

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g = contentPane.getGraphics();
        g.drawImage(videoCap.getOneFrame(), 0, 0, this);
    }

    class MyThread extends Thread{
        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (;;){
                repaint();
                try { Thread.sleep(30);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {    }
            }  
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't you simply do it like `cvtColor(input_image, output_image, COLOR_BGR2RGB)`?

Comment: no in Android studio I could do that but in eclipse it has to be done natively. @Headcrab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent time yesterday trying to break it down and I finally got it to work. The first thing I did was allocate for the new image. which is done in `getSpace`. Then I convert the allocated image, then capture the data from the matrix, then put the data into the image. The last 3 steps all take place in `getImage`. Here is how I solved it.

```
public void getSpace(Mat mat) {
    this.mat = mat;
    int w = mat.cols(), h = mat.rows();
    if (dat == null || dat.length != w * h * 3)
        dat = new byte[w * h * 3];
    if (img == null || img.getWidth() != w || img.getHeight() != h || img.getType() != BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR)
        img = new BufferedImage(w, h, BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);


}

BufferedImage getImage(Mat mat) {
    getSpace(mat);
    mat.get(0, 0, dat);

    for (int i = 0; i < dat.length; i+= 3) {
        byte redChannel = dat[i];
        byte blueChannel = dat[i+2];

        dat[i] = blueChannel;
        dat[i+2] = redChannel;

    }
    img.getRaster().setDataElements(0, 0, mat.cols(), mat.rows(), dat);
    return img;
}
```

The remaining code from the Mat2Image class should be the same that I didn't add in the answer and you can try it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're doing the rearranging of the colors wrong - you're not shifting by enough bits, and you should be using the OR (`|`) rather than the AND (`&`) operator to recombine the color.

Your code:

```
int blueChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 4;
int greenChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF00) >> 2;
int redChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF);
int rgb = (blueChannel) & (greenChannel << 2) & (redChannel << 4);
```

Should become:

```
int blueChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16;
int greenChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8;
int redChannel = (holder[i] & 0xFF);
int rgb = (blueChannel) | (greenChannel << 8) | (redChannel << 16);
```

*EDIT*

Furthermore, it looks like you're not using an `int[]` for your target image, but rather a 3-byte encoding for the color. So it's more likely that you need to do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < holder.length; i++) {
    byte blueChannel = (byte) ((holder[i] & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
    byte greenChannel = (byte) ((holder[i] & 0xFF00) >> 8);
    byte redChannel = (byte) (holder[i] & 0xFF);

    dat[i*3] = redChannel;
    dat[i*3+1] = greenChannel;
    dat[i*3+2] = blueChannel;
```

But it's not clear to me anymore whether you are going from BGR to RGB or the reverse from RGB to BGR. You may need to change the order of the last 3 assignments to get this right.

Comment: It is working better most colors have changed but there the shade between yellow and green is not noticeable

Comment: Actually I think my cast to byte would strip off everything but the last 8 bits so rgb conversion isn't working.

Comment: @cuber I added to my answer but now it's not clear how you could see anything it all, since you were only filling the first 1/3 of the `dat` array.

Comment: you are right I can't now. But this problem with the last image is that it was still with in BGR I am working on going to RGB. I get an out of bounds error saying it is out by 921600 @Erwin Bolwidt

Comment: @cuber you need to adjust the bounds of your for-loop as well. I've just edited the answer

Comment: Interesting, I thought the same thing, however it still giving me the same bounds error. doing `dat.lenght/3` keeps it in bounds but the colors aren't changing the banana is still purple  @Erwin Boldwidt

Comment: check out my answer @Erwin Boldwidt